Click(), moveTo() operations are failing via gitlab ci, webdriverio v9 (same is absolutely working fine in local)
I am using webdriverio v9, facing issues with click(), moveTo() operations. As per the Cucumber steps and logs it shows click() operation is performed but when I see screenshot of that step, UI still on the same step and next step fails. This issue is observed only via gitlab ci, in local its working fine. Both Failed(via gitlab pipeline) and Passed(local) report screenshots attached here
I am using webdriverio v9, facing issues with click(), moveTo() operations. As per the Cucumber steps and logs it shows click() operation is performed but when I see screenshot of that step, UI still on the same step and next step fails. This issue is observed only via gitlab ci, in local its working fine. Both Failed(via gitlab pipeline) and Passed(local) report screenshots attached here
Snippet
Step 1: PASSED
When(/^User click on service plan "(\[^"\]\*)"$/, async (args1) =\> {
const navBarServiceTag = await $('app-navbar-spa-mfe').shadow$('tag-widget-mfe')
const servicePlanButtonEle = await navBarServiceTag.shadow$('#redirect-to-store');
await browser.waitUntil(() =\> servicePlanButtonEle.isClickable())
await servicePlanButtonEle.click();
});

Step 2: FAILED
Then(/^User should be navigated to "(\[^"\]\*)" page$/, async (args1) =\> {
await expect(browser).toHaveUrl(config.baseUrl + '/discover')
});

enter image description here
enter image description here
